# ClipGrab - Error downloading youtube-dl: SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl, youtube, homebrew

I have downloaded YouTube videos using ClipGrab before (v3.8.11), but after updating it (to v3.9.6) I get an error.

First I am informed that an additional dependency "youtube-dl" must be downloaded.

[image]

But when I try to do this I get: `Error downloading youtube-dl: SSL handshake failed`

[image]

I tried installing youtube-dl separately using `brew install youtube-dl` and it appears to have succeeded, but ClipGrab doesn't see this installation, and still gives the SSL error.

I tried going back to my old version of ClipGrab (v3.8.11) but it now gives a different error: `Could not retrieve video link.` So maybe there is some server issue or other problem not local to the app, that is preventing the old version from working too.

**(1)** Is there a way to get around the SSL error or make ClipGrab recognize my brew installation of youtube-dl? **(2)** If there is no way to get the current v3.9.6 working, is there a way to get an older version working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for you (it worked for me). I'm on Kubuntu 22.04, I had to manually download yt-dlp:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/ClipGrab/ClipGrab
wget -P ~/.local/share/ClipGrab/ClipGrab/ \
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp
```

After that clipgrab started working

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about Mac using homebrew but with Linux this was my solution.

Running kubuntu 22.04 Same SSL handshake error
Here is the fix that worked for me..

Download the yt-dlp file from:

https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#release-files

The yt-dlp file found on that page it is the first file in the recommended listing column.

On your computer:
Allow your file manager to show invisible directories/files. Or navigate with the terminal.

Navigate to home/user/.local/share/ClipGrab/ClipGrab/yt-dlp
Overwrite the existing file which will be there but empty, with the file you downloaded from the above link.

Open ClipGrab and the SSL error will be gone and the app will function.